# How to check whether the element exist using chai?

Tags: chai

Using Chai, how can I see whether the element `For example, a div with the class .avatar` exist?

I tried `to.exist` but it's not working.

Comment: Could you share a little bit more code? How did you try to load the `div.avatar` and how exactly does your assertion look like?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`exist`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_exist) language chain in vanilla Chai is used to verify that a plain old JavaScript object is neither `undefined` nor `null`. It sounds like in your case you actually want to be asserting against a DOM element, which vanilla Chai can't do. Instead, you'll need to pull in a Chai plugin like [`chai-jquery`](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery) along with `jQuery` for DOM manipulation. `chai-jquery` allows you to write assertions against elements you have located using `jQuery`, and even provides and overriden form of [`exist`](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery#exist) that would likely serve your purpose exactly. All together, the code you're looking for to assert a `div` with class `avatar` exists would look something like this:

```
expect($('div.avatar')).to.exist;
```

Comment: How about testing a lack of a DOM element? For example, some users logged in have different DOM elements, and I want to test that a not-logged-in user will not show a particular DOM element?

Comment: @Smittles - Please follow the link to `chai-jquery`'s overriden `exist` function that was provided in the answer.

Comment: @JonMitten, though it is very late, you can do something like this. expect(document.querySelectorAll('.nonexistentSelector')).not.to.exist;